# Confusion on Private Information Retrieval by Keywords

Tags: pir

[PIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_information_retrieval) protocols retrieve an item from the database without the server knowing which item it is. But classic CPIR(Computational PIR) or IT-PIR (Information Theoretic PIR) protocols requires the user to know the location address of the object to be retrieved.

Major work on retrieving by Keywords is done [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.21.5506&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and subsequently [here](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2009/cacr2009-37.pdf) extended for SQL databases. An excerpt for more context.

> For B+ tree indices, however, the client uses PIR to traverse the
>   tree. Each block can hold some number m of keys, and at a block level,
>   the B+ tree can be considered an m-ary tree. The client has already
>   been sent the root block of the tree, which contains the top m keys.
>   Using this information, the client can perform a single PIR block
>   query to fetch one of the m blocks so referenced. It repeats this
>   process until it reaches the leaves of the tree, at which point it
>   fetches the required data with further PIR queries. The actual number
>   of PIR queries depends on the height of the (balanced) tree, and the
>   number of tuples in the result set. Traversals of B+ tree indices with
>   our approach are oblivious in that they leak no information about
>   nodes’ access pattern; we realize retrieval of a node’s data as a PIR
>   operation over the data set of all nodes in the tree.

A more general approach is like below

> The main idea in all of our subsequent PERKY constructions is the
>   following: the databases insert $s_1, s_2 .. s_n$ into a data
>   structure which supports search operations on strings. The user
>   conducts an oblivious walk on the data structure until either the word
>   $w$ is found, or User is assured of the fact that $w$ is not one of
>   $s_1, s_2 .. s_n$. Typically, a successful search yields an address
>   which contains data pertaining to the keyword. 
>   A typical search in the data structure involves a sequence of operations, where each operation consists of fetching the contents of a word from memory, performing 
>   a  "local" computation, which depends on the keyword and the fetched
>   contents, and either determining a new address based on the
>   computation, or terminating the search (successfully or
>   unsuccessfully). This sequence of operations can be viewed as a $walk$
>   on the data structure. We now describe a general outline of
>   transforming this walk into an *oblivious walk* on the data structure,
>   namely a walk where each server gets no information on the walk (and,
>   therefore, on the desired keyword itself). For the sake of simplicity,
>   we assume that the data structure has a fixed $root$, a word with
>   known address that is always accessed at the first operation
>   (regardless of the sought keyword).

But either i don't understand it or it seems to be weak. If a $walk$ ends after two iterations then an adversary is pretty sure that the retrieved element is in first two iterations right ? Or how does PIR by keywords in general work? any simpler explanations ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed in this (dated) work is an overkill considering more recent works on the subject. The simplest PIR by keyword construction I could think of is the one based on distributed point functions (DPFs).
see https://cs.idc.ac.il/~elette/FunctionSecretSharing.pdf

Distributed point functions are a special case of function secret sharing (FSS).
FSS is a primitive that is analogous to secret sharing for functions. A dealer shares a function $f:X\to Y$ by sending two shares $f_0$ and $f_1$ to two participants $p_0$ and $p_1$. Given a value $x\in X$ and his share $f_i$, every participant $p_i$ can compute a value $f_i(x)$. We require **security**: share $f_i$ does not reveal any information about $f$, and **correctness**: for every two shares $f_0,f_1$ and a value $x$, it holds that $f_0(x)+f_1(x)=f(x)$.

DPFs are FSS schemes for the class of point functions. These are functions that evaluate zero on all inputs, except one.

Now, to perform PIR-by-keyword over a databse, assume that every record in the data is of the form $(t_i,x_i)$ (a tag and a value). When the client needs to retrieve a value with the tag (or keyword) $t$, he secretly shares the point function $f$ for which $f(t)=1$ and $f(t')=0$ for any $t'\neq t$. He sends each of the shares $f_0,f_1$ to one of the servers. Server $i$, in his turn, computes $x^{(i)}=\sum_{j=1}^N f_i(t_j)x_j$. It is easy to see that from the security of the DPF, the scheme is secure, and from its correctness, the client can compute $x:=x^{(0)}+x^{(1)}$.

The DPF scheme proposed in the work mentioned above costs $O(n)$ bits of communication when the keywords are of size $n$ bits.

Notice that this construction assumes the keywords are all distinct.